# NMinimize and NMaximize stopping evaluating for more complex conditions

Tags: functions, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to obtain the maximum and the minimum of (the negative of) a function F(R,P) given by

```
F = (4 (-1 + R) (9 - 8 R + 3 R^2)^2 (1 - 3 R - 3 P R + P R^2))/(-252 + 
 1221 R - 54 P R - 2087 R^2 - 156 P R^2 - 486 P^2 R^2 + 1683 R^3 + 
 254 P R^3 + 1035 P^2 R^3 - 657 R^4 - 46 P R^4 - 963 P^2 R^4 + 
 108 R^5 - 48 P R^5 + 487 P^2 R^5 + 18 P R^6 - 139 P^2 R^6 + 
 18 P^2 R^7);
```

with R constrained by `2.36<R<2.48` and P constrained by two functions of R,

```
P1 = (-27 - 78 R + 127 R^2 - 23 R^3 - 24 R^4 + 
 9 R^5 + (9 - 8 R + 3 R^2) Sqrt[-1503 + 7926 R - 14849 R^2 + 
   13732 R^3 - 6865 R^4 + 1830 R^5 - 207 R^6])/(R (486 - 1035 R + 
   963 R^2 - 487 R^3 + 139 R^4 - 18 R^5));
```

and

```
P2 = (-1 + 3 R)/((-3 + R) R);
```

The interval on R is defined (with a safety margin) such that P1 and P2 are real and P1<P2. However, when I try evaluating

```
NMaximize[{-F, 2.36 < R < 2.48 && P1 < P < P2}, {R, P}]
```

it simply doesn't evaluate, it just repeats the input.

In previous parts of the code, where F, P1, and P2 were a bit simpler, it didn't have any problems computing, so I don't have any idea of what is happening in this or in other cases of similar complexity. I tried both raising and lowering WorkingPrecision and nothing changed. Any ideas of what could be the problem here?

Comment: Well, for a range of 10, I think so, since the interval for R has length 0.12. But the standard WorkingPrecision is of 16 decimal places, so it shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective function is unbounded from above under the given restictions and `NMaximize` suggests it through

```
NMaximize[{-F,  Reduce[Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0], {P,
 R}, Reals]}, {R, P}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.`{6.92207*10^11, {R -> 2.48, P -> -5.44931}}`

In fact,

```
ForAll[a, a > 100, Exists[{P, R}, -F == a && 
Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0]]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `True`

A different situation with the minimum.

```
NMinimize[{-F,Reduce[Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0], {P,
 R}, Reals]}, {R, P}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution", WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

> `{-963.7138434798351446770398, {R -> 2.366278720834199118174693,  P -> -98.11687377662054190709081}}`

and

```
FindInstance[-F == -10^3 &&  Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0], {P,  R}, Reals]
```

> `{}`

confirms it.

Addition. It appears that the above result on the minimum is not true in view of

```
 FindInstance[-F <= 0 &&Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0], 
{P, R}, Reals]
```

> `{}`

Addition 2. The correct result is likely produced by

```
NMinimize[{-F, Reduce[Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0], 
{P, R}, Reals]}, {R, P}, Method -> "RandomSearch", WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

> `{0, {R -> 2.4800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,  P -> -4.9937965260545905707196029776674937965260545905707}}`

and

```
FindInstance[-F == 10^-20 && Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && 
P < P2, 0], {P,  R}, Reals]
```

> `{{P -> (294584635044699999995653902579616 -  946528 \[Sqrt]\ 96861959589404775389701682926552481250013097016860537)/657447479665,  R -> 155/64}}`

confirms it.

Addition 3.

```
ForAll[a, a > 0,  Exists[{P, R}, -F == a && 
Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0]]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `True`

, but

```
ForAll[a, a >= 0,  Exists[{P, R}, -F == a && 
Rationalize[2.36 < R && R < 2.48 && P1 < P && P < P2, 0]]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `False`

Therefore, zero is the infimum, not the minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive discussion. A couple of curiosities: why did you use Rationalize in the arguments? Does it make the computation faster, perhaps? And is P1<P&&P<P2 better for Mathematica than P1<P<P2?

Comment: @GabrielPicanço: "why did you use Rationalize in the arguments? " -I blow on cold water to avoid round-off errors. "And is `P1<P&&P<P2` better for Mathematica than `P1<P<P2`?" - No, the former is not better, but the former is correct in math sense since `<` is a binary relation.

Answer (score 0):

**correction**

To long for a comment...

Function `F[R,P]`  seems to be bounded inside region `reg`

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[{236/100 <= R <=  248/100, P1 < P < P2}, {R, P}]
Show[Region[reg, PlotRange -> 10], AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> True,PlotRange -> {{2.3, 2.5}, {-12, -4}}]
```

[image]

```
 plot=Plot3D[F, {R, 23 /10, 25/10}, {P, -12, -4} , PlotPoints -> 200, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{R, P}, Element[{R, P}, reg] ],MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), AxesLabel -> {"R", "P", "F"}]
```

[image]

The plot is misleading (thanks @user64494 ) because it doesn't correctly show the pole of function `F` . **That's why the following conclusions concerning the minimum are wrong!**

Min/Max values are approximately between -2.3023 and .0001

```
pts = plot[[1, 1]][[1]];
minmax = SortBy[pts, Last][[{1, -1}]]
(*{{2.40725, -12., -2.3023}, {2.4692, -4.88889, 0.000105768}}*)
```

**Question remains, why `Plot3D` isn't able to plot the whole functiondomain near the poles correctly!**

Comment: Unfortunately, your claim "Min/Max values are approximately between -2.3023 and .0001" contradicts the result of `FindInstance[
 F == -3 && 236/100 <= R <= 248/100 && P1 < P < P2, {R, P}, Reals]` which is `{{R -> 155/64, 
  P -> (-10092445910705 - 29579 Sqrt[102256471552356265])/
    1972342438995}}`. The latter is OK in view of `N[F /. {R -> 155/64, 
   P -> (-10092445910705 - 29579 Sqrt[102256471552356265])/
     1972342438995}]` which produces `-3.` and `P1 < P < P2 /. {R -> 155/64, 
  P -> (-10092445910705 - 29579 Sqrt[102256471552356265])/
    1972342438995}` which is `True`

Comment: Try to find errors in your answer on your own. Good luck!

Comment: More impressive `FindInstance[ F == -300 && 236/100 <= R <= 248/100 && P1 < P < P2, {R, P}, Reals]` results in `{{R -> 155/64, 
  P -> (-1300883379764753 - 29579 Sqrt[1204194562482121097449])/
    197234243899500}}`.

Comment: Hint: As I understand it, your `plot` is misleading (compare with the result of `Plot3D[F, {R, 23/10, 25/10}, {P, -12, -10}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{R, P}, Element[{R, P}, reg]], 
 AxesLabel -> {"R", "P", "F"}, PlotRange -> {-20, 1}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]`).

Comment: Yes you 're right, `plot` is misleading: Plot3D doesn't show the poles. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Upgrade your math: `(-252 + 
 1221 R - 54 P R - 2087 R^2 - 156 P R^2 - 486 P^2 R^2 + 1683 R^3 + 
 254 P R^3 + 1035 P^2 R^3 - 657 R^4 - 46 P R^4 - 963 P^2 R^4 + 
 108 R^5 - 48 P R^5 + 487 P^2 R^5 + 18 P R^6 - 139 P^2 R^6 + 
 18 P^2 R^7)==0` is a singular line of `F`, not its pole (There are no poles of functions of several variables.).

Comment: I wonder the upvote for the wrong answer, BTW, it seems  Ulrich Neumann  did not read my correct answer before having posted his one. That upvote does not make a good impression.

Comment: @user64494 I only wonder about the incredible style of your comments... By the way a "pole" is an "isolated singularity", though no reason to upgrade my math